# Forcing VS to use an assembly with a lower version

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

This is a general question but I will describe my specific scenario - My project is a .NET Core 3.0 SignalR Console application in VS19 (same with VS17)

After upgrading everything to Core 3.0 build now fails with:

```
Error CS1705 Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client' with identity
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common, 
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version 
than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common' with identity 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

What I understand is that despite the nuget highest version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common` being 1.0.0.0, for some reason `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` requires 3.0.0.0 which does not exist (yet).

How can I tell VS to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common 1.0.0.0 instead ?

I tried in my csproj to add specific version to the reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common" Version="1.1.0">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</PackageReference>
```

But nothing changed. I also tried with `<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>`, same result :(

Any help ?

Comment: Shouldn't `SpecificVersion` be set to `True`?

Comment: thanks! same result, updated my question

Comment: There is a `dev` feed for some `netcore` libraries here: https://dotnet.myget.org/f/aspnetcore-dev/
You can add that to your `nuget` feed list and you should be able to find the 3.0.0 prerelease version

Comment: oh .. how do I add to nuget feed list in VS ?

Comment: In VS, open the Manage Nuget packages window, top right click the 'cog' and you can add the feed in the dialog (click the red + and add it to the bottom of the list)

Comment: I did but it still can't find Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common > 1.0.0.0

Comment: You need to select the new feed in the `Package source` and click the `include prerelease` button

Comment: ha it worked !! thank you .. if you post an answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the `.NET Core` prerelease libraries aren't available on the main `NuGet` feed. You need to add the nightly/dev feed to your `NuGet` package sources and, hopefully, it should be available there.

The feeds are:

**ASP.NET Core**

https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-dev

**.NET Core**

https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json

To add the feed to Visual Studio

1. In the Manage NuGet Packages window for your project click on the cog in the top right corner.
2. In the new dialog click the red 'x' in the top right
3. Paste the URL above in the "Source" tex box
4. Give the feed a name (e.g. ASP.NET Core Dev)
5. Click Update
6. Ensure the feed is at the bottom of the list (so this is the last one used for packages)
7. Click OK

Now you can change the Package Source in the NuGet window to either your new feed or "All" and click the 'include prerelease' to see the pre-release versions of the packages.

Comment: Also after all above in package manager next to 'package source' in the top right select 'All'

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated the answer with the additional link :-)